# It is possible to get the PID from a given file descriptor( programmatically using C++)?

Tags: c++, linux

I have seen lot of tutorials and documentation on how to get the files descriptors from a given pid. Well, I want to do otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise than what, now? Are you maybe looking for the source code for [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Ben already answer me.

Comment: It's system-specific. You can do it on linux for example, using SO_PEERCRED to fetch the peer's ucred.pid. Similarly, Solaris has getpeerucred to fetch the peer's zone+pid.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I'm actually working with linux .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not, that's like trying to get the PID that called `main`.  Every process has a file descriptor 0 (`stdin`), 1, 2, etc., and they mean different things for each process.

A file descriptor, which is just a small integer, isn't meaningful unless you already know what process you are talking about.